Getting the dispersion parameter from a negative binomial regression in python
R code to find the dispersion parameter of the negative binomial regression model.
mod.Syn.L.plusGamma <- glm.nb(Syn ~ offset(I(1*log(L))), data = Lang.data)
r = mod.Syn.L.plusGamma$theta

The dispersion parameter theta is estimated by the glm model in R. model summary below:
Call:
glm.nb(formula = Syn ~ offset(I(1 * log(L))), data = Lang.data, 
    init.theta = 71.78887386, link = log)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -11.2986     0.1231  -91.77   <2e-16 ***


Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(71.7889) family taken to be 1)
    Null deviance: 494.73  on 3397  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 494.73  on 3397  degrees of freedom
AIC: 630.26

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1


          Theta:  72 
      Std. Err.:  1537 
Warning while fitting theta: iteration limit reached 

 2 x log-likelihood:  -626.26

Trying to replicate the same model in python:
def model_3(data):
    formula = "Syn ~ 1"
    data['log_L'] = np.log(data['L']) 
    model = smf.glm(formula=formula, 
                    data=data, 
                    family=sm.families.NegativeBinomial(), 
                    offset=data['log_L'], 
                    observed=False).fit()
    return model

Model summary from regression model in python:
Generalized Linear Model Regression Results                  
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                    Syn   No. Observations:                 3398
Model:                            GLM   Df Residuals:                     3397
Model Family:        NegativeBinomial   Df Model:                            0
Link Function:                    Log   Scale:                          1.0000
Method:                          IRLS   Log-Likelihood:                -313.43
Date:                Tue, 11 Jun 2024   Deviance:                       445.59
Time:                        14:20:10   Pearson chi2:                 3.37e+03
No. Iterations:                     6   Pseudo R-squ. (CS):              0.000
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept    -11.2997      0.125    -90.506      0.000     -11.544     -11.055
==============================================================================

Model intercept and other variables are nearly identical to the values produced by the model in R however the dispersion parameter is not estimated during the process. Some sources mention that the dispersion parameter theta and the shape parameter alpha are aggregated so their value will be equal to one which is the scale but I am not sure if that is completely true. What is clear is that alpha and theta are not directly accessible from the model.
Are there other ways to estimate the dispersion parameter, maybe from the other model values such as variance and mu?

discrete.NegativeBinomial computes the dispersion parameter as part of maximum likelihood fit. GLM is a one-parameter family and assumes that parameter is fixed by user. I can be estimated by the user by profile likelihood, e.g. optimize llf wrt. the negative binomial family parameter.
